# Plot a tidy map of English regions

Tags: r, rgdal

I'm trying to plot a tidy map of English regions in R. I'm using code that runs successfully on other shapefiles, but when I run this the code executes without error, but then just presents a blank image. I can plot the blank map using traditional methods, and the tidy object looks fine to me, so I'm at a loss to understand what's going on.

This is the code I'm using:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(rgdal)

# load and check the English regions map
eng_reg_map <- readOGR(
  dsn = "./Region_(December_2015)_Boundaries"
)

plot(eng_reg_map)

# make a tidy map
tidy_eng_reg_map <- tidy(eng_reg_map, region = "rgn15nm")

# blank map
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = tidy_eng_reg_map, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "white", colour = "black") +
  theme_void() +
  coord_map()
```

The shapefile I'm using is available [here](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/ons::region-december-2015-boundaries/explore?layer=4&location=52.815129%2C-1.186709%2C5.90) (you have to select the shapefile from the list - sorry I can't provide a direct link).

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

(Cross-posting on Stack Overflow)

**Edit**
A friend got me halfway there: the problem is that latitude and longitude are in British-style Eastings and Northings, not global co-ordinates. Anyone know a way to convert them using `rgdal`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shapefile is in OSGB coordinates (basically a planar system of metres N and E of a point off the SW of Cornwall) and `coord_map` only works with lat-long degrees, it seems.

Transforming the `sp` object to lat-long produces results:

```
eng_reg_map=spTransform(eng_reg_map, "+init=epsg:4326")
[and then tidy etc]
```

BUT you might want to consider using the `sf` package for spatial data, in which case you can do nice maps without having to unwrap everything with this `tidy` function using either the `tmap` package or `geom_sf`.

`rgdal` and `sp` objects are not long for this world.

Comment: Thanks so much - worked like a charm! If you want to post the same answer on SO I'll upvote it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73621382/plot-a-tidy-map-of-english-regions)

Comment: What I like about the `tidy` approach is that it makes it very transparent to join in metadata about the regions (which is what I ultimately want to display). Do you have any advice on doing that in a post-tidy world?

Comment: With `sf` the polygons are single rows of a data frame, and you just do merge and join like its any other data frame. You are only having to do `tidy` here (which I think is like `fortify`) to get the data into an expanded form for `geom_polygons`, which repeats each polygon attribute for each polygon *vertex* and is extremely memory inefficient and slow.

Comment: Thanks, got it now - I didn't realise I could do straightforward joins to these big geospatial objects - you've been a great help

Comment: Work through https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/index.html